# Why is there an unresolved compilation error? (custom exception handling)

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I'm practicing writing custom exception handling code in Java and have run into a bit of an issue with the following code. It's supposed to ask the user to input a string, and if that string is empty then it will throw a custom exception.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testException2 {

    public static void customStringException(String s) throws NoStringException {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            throw new NoStringException("customStringException");
        }
        System.out.println("String input found.");
    }
    
    //THIS IS LINE 12
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any string: ");
        String s = key.nextLine();
        try {        
            customStringException(s);
        }
        catch(NoStringException e) {
            System.out.println("No string input found");
        }
        key.close();
    }
    
}


class NoStringException extends Exception {
    NoStringException(String error) {
       super(error);
    }
}
```

I've successfully written similar code when it came to taking in int and double inputs, but the same is not working for string input.

The exact error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

        at testException2.main(public class testException2 {.java:12)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If I paste your code for example into ideone it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: That is bizarre, it might be an issue with my compiler. I will try different ones then, thank you! @ThomasKläger